# How to query a body on grapghql in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful, gatsby-plugin

I'm trying to create a blog using a tutorial from 2019 which use the `contentful-plugin` but I saw gastby has updated their documentation so I cannot do what I saw on the video, my problem is, I'm not quite understand the documentation see below.

when I start to query using the `http://localhost:8000/___graphql`
before It was

```
query {
  allContentfulBlogPost (
    filter: {node_locale: {eq: "en-US"}}
    sort: {
      fields: publishedDate,
      order: DESC
    }
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        title node_locale
        slug
        publishedDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
        body {
          json
        }
          
          
        
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I saw on the Contentful documentation
`Note: Be aware that previous versions of the Gatsby Contentful source plugin used a json field. This got replaced with raw to give you more flexibility in rendering and to fix performance issues.`

```
query {
  allContentfulBlogPost {
    edges {
      node {
        bodyRichText {
          raw
          references {
            ... on ContentfulAsset {
              contentful_id
              fixed(width: 1600) {
                width
                height
                src
                srcSet
              }
            }
            ... on ContentfulBlogPost {
              contentful_id
              title
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On graphql I don't have this `bodyRichText`, I just have `body { raw }` but using this one like:

```
export const query = graphql`
    query($slug: String!) {
        contentfulBlogPost(slug: {eq: $slug}) {
            title
            publishedDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
            body {
                raw
            }
        }


    }


`

const Blog = (props) => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <h1>{props.data.contentfulBlogPost.title}</h1>
            <p>{props.data.contentfulBlogPost.publishedDate}</p>
            {documentToReactComponents(props.data.contentfulBlogPost.body.raw)}
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default Blog
```

IS NOT WORKING So I am missing something but I couldn't find out what it is.

Comment: Can you clarify "what is not working"? What's the output, the logs, etc

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `body` is now deprecated in favor of `raw`, to give us more flexibility when creating a custom output when sourcing from Contentful.

The idea, given a query like:

```
query {
  allContentfulBlogPost {
    edges {
      node {
        bodyRichText {
          raw
          references {
            ... on ContentfulAsset {
              contentful_id
              fixed(width: 1600) {
                width
                height
                src
                srcSet
              }
            }
            ... on ContentfulBlogPost {
              contentful_id
              title
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't have the `bodyRichText` node, check for their availability at `localhost:8000/___graphql`. The output should be exactly the same.

After getting the response object and the references, the idea is using the Contentful supported [Richtext React Renderer](https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/tree/master/packages/rich-text-react-renderer):

```
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
​
const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>
const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>
​
const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Embedded Asset</h2>
          <pre>
            <code>{JSON.stringify(node, null, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
        </>
      )
    },
  },
}
​
renderRichText(node.bodyRichText, options)
```

The idea when using these connectors is to customize the output. Using:

```
{documentToReactComponents(props.data.contentfulBlogPost.body.raw)}
```

Will never produce the expected output. Maybe your are looking for:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.data.contentfulBlogPost.body.raw}} />;
```

Since it's raw content.

Comment: I don't know if I put on the correct place my reply to you. I have edited your answer because the Stackoverflow does not allow to comment with big text - Sorry I'm new using this forum

Comment: Use it like this: https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/tree/master/packages/rich-text-react-renderer here you have an example. Here too: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#rendering